# Get the Query Fired using PreparedStatement with the bind variables on Oracle Database

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, prepared-statement

**EDIT:** I am using Oracle

I am Writing a dynamic query using `PreparedStatement` which goes something like this

```
String query="UPDATE <tablename> SET 
        column1=?,column2=?,.....,coulmn7=? WHERE "
        + "column5=TO_DATE(?,'DD/MM/YYYY') AND "
        + "column6=? AND "
        ....
        + "column7=?";

PreparedStatement prest2=con2.PrepareThisStatement(query);

while(true){

   //loop through and bind values
   if(end of list) break;
}
 prest2.executeUpdate(query);
```

I need to keep the track of the queries that get fired at the database and log them in a table.

But I cannot get the entire query when using the `PreparedStatement`, nor can I store the values in a separate field. Is there a way to get the final query that was fired at the database.

Comment: True. exact duplicate.

Comment: @PradeepSimha: Edited the Post Please see, the suggestions to print the `PreparedStatement` don't while working with Oracle. I also dont want to use a logging api.

Comment: @SangeetMenon, as far as I know there is no facility in JDBC to achieve the same. As far as I know it will work only with MySQL drivers.

Answer (score 0):

You Can, using 1`prest2.toString();`